# WPS server on Linux or Raspberry

Tags: raspberry-pi, hostapd, wps

I configured hostapd to make an Access Point Wi-Fi network on my raspberry pi... everything works fine. It acts like a router.

Can i bind client devices via WPS? For example phones, ESP8266 that support WPS connections?

Comment: I figure out by myself... you can't have WPS on Raspberry Pi 3.

Comment: You can combine a WPS daemon, say this: https://sourceforge.net/projects/wpsd/?source=typ_redirect with making the RPi an access point as indicated here: https://frillip.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-with-hostapd/

I'm working on this. If it's successful, I'll convert this comment to an answer

Comment: @Irwin -- how did this go? I am looking for the same.

Comment: @pperrin according to my research it's not possibile. I did a workaround

Comment: Gosh, I did it and forgot to come back to update, here. Very sorry. It worked.  If I can find the architecture of the solution, I'll share it.

Comment: If you can share your solution we'll appreciate :)